# JS and SWF calling issue

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm using ZeroClipboard code to add a copy button to my page. It was working perfect when everything was in the same folder, but when I started classifying everything, like .js in a folder and .swf in another folder, the script stopped working. (NOTE: testing on localhost WAMP Server).

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
```

And here is the part of the JS that is not working/causing problem:

```
moviePath: '/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf', // URL to movie
```

Before, when the JS and the SWF were in the same folder, it worked perfectly. Now when separated, it is not working. Here are all the trials I made:

```
moviePath: './swf/ZeroClipboard.swf', // URL to movie
moviePath: '../swf/ZeroClipboard.swf', // URL to movie
moviePath: 'swf/ZeroClipboard.swf', // URL to movie
```

None worked and the error returned (using Google Chrome Javascript Console):

```
**GET http://localhost/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf 404 (Not Found)**
```

Anyone else facing this? Anyone know how to override/solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache check your .htaccess file and

```
/var/log/apache2/access_log  
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

for detailed info

Comment: this is the line I see related to the swf (`127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2012:16:46:04 +0200] "GET /swf/ZeroClipboard.swf HTTP/1.1" 404 219`)

Comment: My .htaccess file is for password protection only

Comment: you don't have this file in this directory, or your apache is wrongly configured and cannot see it. try disabling .htacess or changing apache directory configuration to see whats wrong

Comment: the problem is calling the swf. When both were in the same directory everything worked, but when I had each of them in a different directory, the js goes looking for the folder that contains the swf in the root directory and not the `parent directory/swf/file.swf`